# Editing smali. Issue : Low 16 bits must be zeroed out. Is the hexadecimal id is wrong?

Tags: android, edit, reverse-engineering, smali, apktool

Good morning/afternoon/evening, I am quiet a newbie in smali language and, while compiling, there is an issue I can't solve. I hope this question has not been asked before, but I checked out Google and some threads on stackoverflow and couldn't find any solution, so I assume that it hasn't. So, what happens :

I am trying to modify the C1.smali file of my app, I just want to change the wrong id of an array. So i just replaced the id, I didn't touch anything else.

The **smali file** after modification :

```
.line 52
invoke-virtual {p0}, Lcom/one/aplication/C1;->getResources()Landroid/content/res/Resources;

move-result-object v6

const/high16 v7, 0x7f060001
# array "Codes", id was 0x7f050000

invoke-virtual {v6, v7}, Landroid/content/res/Resources;->getStringArray(I)[Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v5
```

Of course, I verified that the id was correct, by checking the **public.xml**  file(in res\values). I let you see by yourself :

```
 <public type="string" name="name1" id="0x7f05003d" />
<public type="string" name="surname1" id="0x7f05003e" />
<public type="array" name="server" id="0x7f060000" />
<public type="array" name="Codes" id="0x7f060001" />
<public type="menu" name="search" id="0x7f070000" />
<public type="id" name="txt" id="0x7f080000" />
<public type="id" name="button1" id="0x7f080001" />
```

Now, when i want to recompile, **apktool** throw an issue that i can't understand :
`C:\apktool>apktool b CC
I: Using Apktool 2.0.0-RC4
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Smaling smali folder into classes.dex...
CC\smali\com\one\aplication\C1.smali[58,4] Invalid literal value: 2131099649.
Low 16 bits must be zeroed out.
Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: Could not smali file
: com/one/aplication/C1.smali
        at brut.androlib.src.SmaliBuilder.buildFile(SmaliBuilder.java:71)
        at brut.androlib.src.SmaliBuilder.build(SmaliBuilder.java:55)
        at brut.androlib.src.SmaliBuilder.build(SmaliBuilder.java:41)
        at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildSourcesSmali(Androlib.java:354)
        at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildSources(Androlib.java:294)
        at brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Androlib.java:280)
        at brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Androlib.java:255)
        at brut.apktool.Main.cmdBuild(Main.java:225)
        at brut.apktool.Main.main(Main.java:84)`

Do someone know something about the cause of this issue? The apktool issue is pointing to the line [58] which is the line I modified. I really don't know what happens! Thanks to anybody who will try to help me, and please excuse my poor English. Have a good day! :)

Comment: if the app is yours why are you editing smali instead of Java files?

Comment: I try to learn how to edit smali files on my own app because I exactly know how it works. In the future, when I will have get some knowledge, I will start working on apks that are not mine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the raw bytecode, the `const/high16` instruction accepts a 16-bit operand, which is then shifted left 16 bits before being loaded into the register. In smali 2.0 and up, the operand is given in the post-shifted form, which requires, of course, that the least-significant 16 bits are all 0s.

For example, to load the value 0x12340000 into a register, you could use

```
const/high16 0x12340000
```

And in the raw bytecode, the operand would be represented as the 16 bit value "0x1234".

The value 0x7f060001 does not meet this requirement, so it can't be used with the `const/high16` instruction. You could instead use the `const` instruction.

```
const v7, 0x7f060001
```

Comment: It works perfectly now, thanks a lot Jesus! I have now the same issue with other classes, I'm going to do the same. You helped me a lot, have a nice day. :)